# ¿como cambiar de "variable" un contador++ en javascript para no tener que repetirlo?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un contador que incrementa su valor en cada click que llama a una función, dentro de esta, también se hace un switch. ¿Como puedo hacer para no tener que generar tantos contadores++ como case? Aquí el código:

```
var contador1 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;    
function llegaid(llega_id){//aqui llega un 1 o un 2 o un 3 o un 4 etc;
    var i = llega_id;
    switch (i) {
    
    case "1":               
    contador1++;    
    //Aqui hago unas acciones que deben contar desde 1
    break;
    
    case "2":               
    contador2++;    
    //Aqui hago unas acciones que deben contar desde 1 y si repitiera contador1++ se acumulan los 
    //click y eso no debe suceder;
    break;
    //Aqui van muchos mas case y tendría que generar varios contadores1234++.
    default:
    }
    
    }
```

Lo que me gustaría es que "un solo" contador pudiera estar en todos los case, y empezar de uno, sin eliminar los click que lleva el otro contador. Intenté lo siguiente pero no me funciono:

```
var contador = 0;//Esto es lo importante    
function llegaid(llega_id){//aqui llega un 1 o un 2 o un 3 o un 4 etc;
    var i = llega_id;
    switch (i) {
    
    case "1":               
    contador[i]++;  
    //Aqui hago unas acciones que deben contar desde 1
    break;
    
    case "2":               
    contador[i]++;  
    break;
    //Aqui hago unas acciones que deben contar desde 1
    //Aqui van muchos mas case
    default:
    }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un simple objeto:

```
const contadores = { };

function llegaid( llega_id ){
    if( !( llega_id in contadores ) ) { contadores[llega_id] = 0; }

    contadores[llega_id]++;

    switch( llega_id ) {
    
    case "1":
        ...
        break;
    
    case "2":
        ....
        break;

    default:
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Woooooow! ¡Genial! ¡Brutal! ¡Mil gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Tu aproximación es casi correcta, tendrías que tener un contador en un `Array`, donde cada índice se correspondería con un `case`. Toma en cuenta que los índices de los `Array` comienzan en cero.

Puedes crear un `Array` de contadores en cero con:

```
let contador = (new Array(<cantidad_de_case>)).fill(0);
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const cantidad_de_case = 5;
let contador = (new Array(cantidad_de_case)).fill(0);
const aumentar_contador = () => {
  let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * cantidad_de_case);
  switch(id) {
    case 0:
      contador[id] += 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      contador[id] += 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      contador[id] += 1;
      break;
    case 3:
      contador[id] += 1;
      break;
    case 4:
      contador[id] += 1;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

let salida = document.getElementById('salida');
let boton = document.getElementById('aumentar');
boton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  aumentar_contador();
  salida.innerHTML = `
    <ul>Contadores:
      <li>Contador 1: ${contador[0]}</li>
      <li>Contador 2: ${contador[1]}</li>
      <li>Contador 3: ${contador[2]}</li>
      <li>Contador 4: ${contador[3]}</li>
      <li>Contador 5: ${contador[4]}</li>
    </ul>
  `
});
```

```html
<button id="aumentar">Aumentar Contador</button><br>
<div id="salida"></div>
```

En este caso muy particular, parece código repetitivo, pero la idea está allí, sólo necesitas conocer de antemano la cantidad de casos que vas a manejar.